# Using a neural net to make predictions

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I want to use a neural net to give predictions, but I am not sure where to start. I do know that I don't want to use the high-level `Predict` function.

So what I have is a series of optical spectroscopies, which each corresponds to a single number from 0 to 1.

For example, in the plot attached, curves with different colors correspond to different numbers. Say, yellow curves correspond to 0.4 and red curves correspond to 0.8. I want to train the neural net so that when I input new curve data (meaning a list of numbers), it outputs a number between 0 to 1.

***In short, what I want is:
Input(a list of numbers) ---> Neural Net ---> Output(a single number between 0 to 1)***

What kind of neural net should I use? Any examples? I didn't find any on the Neural Net Repository.

[image]

Comment: It seems you'd have to train your network yourself...that a specific list of data corresponds to a specific number between 0 and 1...though my guess is that you'll need a lot of already defined curves since your lines only really seem to have a small area that are different than each other.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you could share your data.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a [blog post](https://blog.wolfram.com/2018/05/31/how-optimistic-do-you-want-to-be-bayesian-neural-network-regression-with-prediction-errors/) in the past that should help you get started with this. The documentation also has two pages that might be of interest to you:

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksRegression.html#280210622
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksRegressionWithUncertainty.html

Comment: Thank you for sharing this and for writing that blog post (which I've read before and appreciated at the time.) Consider posting this as a comment though, since link-only answers are [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/209838).

Comment: @Sjoerd Smit Your blog is very helpful, I already solved the problem following your solution. Thanks